# Content duplication issue with dynamic URLs

Tags: urls, post-duplication

My WordPress blog creates many dynamic URLs, which creates a content duplication issue for my website. As each page gets a different live URL, it's being considered as a duplicate page.

Why are dynamic URLs getting indexed and creating this content duplication issue?

Example 01:

- example.com/travel/lorem-ipsum-dolar
- example.com/travel/tag/lorem-ipsum-dolar

Example 02:

- example.com/travel/lorem-ipsum-dolar
- example.com/travel/tag/lorem-ipsum-dolar?view=session_id=1013

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not necessarily with wordpress, rather Google allows you to exclude specific url parameters.

So you should exclude the session_id parameter, and possible others... have a look around the Craw->url parameters section of you webmaster account. There are a number of different options, depending on what the roles of your parameters are.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters?